# Tensorflow.Variables - a bit confusing

Tags: tensorflow

Quick question about some code:

```
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
```

In code above I'm defining two variables and parameter for my linear_model operation. What is confusing to me is that when I go to execute the method, one of the parameters that I can pass to my linear_model method is the following:

```
sess.run(linear_model, {x: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

How is this possible? I only have once placeholder, so is the array consider my parameter? How can this be evaluated?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking. Why is it that you think that last line of code should be impossible?

Answer (score 0):

because `linear_model = W * x + b` is valid operation. if you change shape of W to (2,3), you will get a error.

PS: W*x +b is a scalar multiple vector then add a scalar elemen-wise.

Comment: What did you mean by "a scalar multiple vector then add a scalar element-wise"?

Comment: Also, why are the variables W and b has an array of .3 and -.3?

Comment: x is a vecter [1,2,3,4], w is 0.3. so W*x is [0.3,0.6,...], then minus   b (0.3) from the result? I am a bit confused of  what you want to do. you write the formula yourself, you seems don't understand them.